# smartsheet-Accesstoken regeneration for oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule4, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have created an app in developer tools and performing step1 to get the authorization code on callback url
step1:
https://app.smartsheet.com/b/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=vztdl8m9evf73v4fumz&scope=READ_SHEETS%20WRITE_SHEETS&state=MY_STATE

step1 will call redirect url and gives code which is used in step2 below

step2:
https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=vztdl8m9evf73v4fumz&code=i58077psfhsglxru&client_secret=jstivmg6zwvffhhdlib

With the refresh_token from above I am getting refresh_token to access the smartsheet data.
step3:
https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token?client_id=vztdl8m9evf73v4fumz&client_secret=jstivmg6zwvffhhdlib&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=qhetlorupehbdob3ujfjo7q0r3

But code generated in step1 expires in 599531.How to get new authorization code again? I want to automate all this process in Mule 4 with HTTP requests. Step2 and step3 I am clear. But I am unable to automate the step1. Calling this on postman is giving some html response

Comment: By MuleSoft do you mean MuleSoft's Mule Runtime 4?

Comment: Yes in Mule4. I tried using smartsheet connector but getting an error that Oauth dance could not be performed with resourceOwnerId. So trying this direct api access approach